# ASP MVC Migration error: Type is not resolved for member

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration

I'm having issues using migrations in my asp mvc application.
When I try the following commands: enable-migrations, add-migration,.. I receive the following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextType(String
>   contextTypeName) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String
>   contextTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Type is not resolved for member
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

How should I Fix this? Already tried reinstalling `EntityFramework` using NuGet.

Greets

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The fix: there was "&" in the project's path. I have removed it.

This was useful: [migrate.exe common problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx)